# Symfony Doctrine UniqueEntity repositoryMethod

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have entity Users and three unique fields and use for this @UniqueEntity, but I don't know how in message visible exactly fields already in DB ? I think maybe like Assert annotation

```
 * @Assert\Type(
 *     type="array",
 *     message="The value {{ value }} is not a valid {{ type }}."
 * )
```

but not work

my entity:

```
/**
* Users.
*
* @ORM\Table(name="users")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\UsersRepository")
* @ExclusionPolicy("all")
* @UniqueEntity(
*     fields={"email", "telephone", "skype"},
*     errorPath="entity",
*     message="This email, telephone or skype is already."
* )
*/
class Users implements UserInterface
{
use Timestampable;
    /**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255,  unique=true, nullable=true)
 * @Expose()
 * @Assert\Length(min=3, max=255)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Email()
 */
protected $email;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="skype", type="string", length=255, unique=true, nullable=true)
 * @Assert\Length(min=3, max=255)
 * @Expose()
 */
protected $skype;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="telephone", type="string", length=255, unique=true, nullable=true)
 * @Assert\Length(min=3, max=255)
 * @Expose()
 */
protected $telephone;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have configure the constraint with the unique of the tuple: combination value of the field email telephone and skype is unique.

From the [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html#fields):

> This required option is the field (or list of fields) on which this
>   entity should be unique. For example, if you specified both the email
>   and name field in a single UniqueEntity constraint, then it would
>   enforce that the combination value is unique (e.g. two users could
>   have the same email, as long as they don't have the same name also).
>
> **If you need to require two fields to be individually unique (e.g. a unique email and a unique username), you use two UniqueEntity entries,
>   each with a single field.**

So you need to specify three different unique constraint, as example:

```
/**
* Users.
*
* @ORM\Table(name="users")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\UsersRepository")
* @ExclusionPolicy("all")
* @UniqueEntity(
*     fields="email",
*     errorPath="entity",
*     message="This email is already in use."
* @UniqueEntity(
*     fields="telephone",
*     errorPath="entity",
*     message="This telephone is already in use."
* @UniqueEntity(
*     fields="skype",
*     errorPath="entity",
*     message="This skype account is already in use."
* )
*/
class Users implements UserInterface
```

Hope this help